# Getting a Json information

Tags: java, json, api, twitch, minimal-json

I am coding in Java and I'm using the [minimal-json](https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json) library. I am trying to get some information from a json text (idk if it's an array).

I'm trying to access the "game" value inside "stream", but I always get a crash by nullpointer or a parseexception.

Here is the json string I'm trying to get (From the Twitch Api):

`{"_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/hackerc0w","channel":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w"},"stream":{"_id":13817896816,"game":"Programming","viewers":13,"created_at":"2015-04-01T13:54:54Z","video_height":1080,"average_fps":59.9235368156,"_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/hackerc0w"},"preview":{"small":"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_hackerc0w-80x45.jpg","medium":"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_hackerc0w-320x180.jpg","large":"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_hackerc0w-640x360.jpg","template":"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_hackerc0w-{width}x{height}.jpg"},"channel":{"_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w","follows":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w/follows","commercial":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w/commercial","stream_key":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w/stream_key","chat":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/chat/hackerc0w","features":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w/features","subscriptions":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w/subscriptions","editors":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w/editors","videos":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w/videos","teams":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w/teams"},"background":null,"banner":null,"broadcaster_language":"en","display_name":"hackerc0w","game":"Programming","logo":null,"mature":false,"status":"Coding a Chatbot in C","partner":false,"url":"http://www.twitch.tv/hackerc0w","video_banner":null,"_id":41236491,"name":"hackerc0w","created_at":"2013-03-11T17:08:22Z","updated_at":"2015-04-01T17:17:44Z","delay":0,"followers":28,"profile_banner":null,"profile_banner_background_color":null,"views":2948,"language":"de"}}}`

The way I got if the livestreamer was live was like this:

`public static boolean isStreamLive(String channel) {
  try {
    URL url = new URL(TWITCH_STREAM.replace("$c$", channel)) );
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( conn.getInputStream() ));
    String inputLine = br.readLine();
    br.close();
    JsonObject jsonObj = JsonObject.readFrom(inputLine);
    return ( jsonObj.get("stream").isNull() )?false:true;
  } catch (IOException e) {
    return false;
  }
}`

And I mostly tried to copy the method above. But I have been checking the documentation of the library to know and I have been trying a lot of things.
The last was this:

`public static String checkGame(String channel) {
  if (!isStreamLive(channel)) return "El Estreamer esta Offline!";
  try {
    URL url = new URL(  insertChannel(TWITCH_STREAM, channel) );
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( conn.getInputStream() ));
    String inputLine = br.readLine();
    br.close();
    JsonObject object = JsonObject.readFrom(inputLine);
    JsonValue value = object.get("stream").asObject();
    String msg = value.valueOf("status").toString();
    return msg;
  } catch (IOException e) {
    return "Algo raro paso :/ error: 3";
  }
  return channel; 
}`

Comment: btw ignore the channel, isnt my channel, its a friend

Comment: The line that crashes is the one that I get the value of, also theres the edit

Comment: thnxs @azurefrog for the editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two main problems with the code you've shown.

The first problem that you're having is that you're trying to get the status out of the wrong nested object.  You're getting the `stream` object from the original json and then trying to get the value of the `status` key from that, but in the json you've posted `status` is part of a nested `channel` object.

The structure of the json object is like so:

```
{
    "_links": { ... },
    "stream": {
        ...
        "channel":{
            "_links": { ...  },
            ...
            "status":"Coding a Chatbot in C",
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

... so you can't get `status` directly from `stream`, you need to get `channel` from `stream` and get the `status` from *that*.

---

The second problem is that you're trying to use `valueOf()` to pull a value out of a `JsonObject`.  `valueOf()` is a *static* method which creates a new object based on the supplied input, so it doesn't actually use data in the object you call it on.

Calling `value.valueOf("status")` will completely ignore data in `value` and create a new `JsonObject` containing the string **"status"**.

If you want to get the value of a nested object, you need to drill down to it with a series of successive `get("objName").asObject()` calls, and then call `.get("key")` to obtain the value you want:

```
    // hardcoded for example, actually would be read from BufferedReader
    String inputLine = "{\"_links\":{\"self\":\"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/hackerc0w\",\"channel\":\"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w\"},\"stream\":{\"_id\":13817896816,\"game\":\"Programming\",\"viewers\":13,\"created_at\":\"2015-04-01T13:54:54Z\",\"video_height\":1080,\"average_fps\":59.9235368156,\"_links\":{\"self\":\"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/hackerc0w\"},\"preview\":{\"small\":\"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_hackerc0w-80x45.jpg\",\"medium\":\"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_hackerc0w-320x180.jpg\",\"large\":\"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_hackerc0w-640x360.jpg\",\"template\":\"http://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_hackerc0w-{width}x{height}.jpg\"},\"channel\":{\"_links\":{\"self\":\"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w\",\"follows\":\"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w/follows\",\"commercial\":\"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w/commercial\",\"stream_key\":\"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w/stream_key\",\"chat\":\"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/chat/hackerc0w\",\"features\":\"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w/features\",\"subscriptions\":\"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w/subscriptions\",\"editors\":\"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w/editors\",\"videos\":\"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w/videos\",\"teams\":\"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/hackerc0w/teams\"},\"background\":null,\"banner\":null,\"broadcaster_language\":\"en\",\"display_name\":\"hackerc0w\",\"game\":\"Programming\",\"logo\":null,\"mature\":false,\"status\":\"Coding a Chatbot in C\",\"partner\":false,\"url\":\"http://www.twitch.tv/hackerc0w\",\"video_banner\":null,\"_id\":41236491,\"name\":\"hackerc0w\",\"created_at\":\"2013-03-11T17:08:22Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2015-04-01T17:17:44Z\",\"delay\":0,\"followers\":28,\"profile_banner\":null,\"profile_banner_background_color\":null,\"views\":2948,\"language\":\"de\"}}}";

    JsonObject object = JsonObject.readFrom(inputLine);    // parse json into object
    JsonObject stream = object.get("stream").asObject();   // get "stream" sub-object
    JsonObject channel = stream.get("channel").asObject(); // get "channel" sub-object
    JsonValue status = channel.get("status");              // get the value of "status"
    String msg = status.asString();
    System.out.println(msg);  // Coding a Chatbot in C
```